# regarding the compatiblity of components or modules with Different versions of Joomla(3)

Tags: php

Just I have one doubt that why one component or module is compatiable with one version of Joomla(Ex-> Joomla 2.5) but the same component or module is not compatiable with another version of Joomla(Ex-> Joomla 3.0).

If I want to make it compatiable with another versions also then what changes I need to do

Answer (score 0):

The problem with compatibility is Joomla! is a delicate one.

**The Joomla! platform / API is evolving all the time** (especially between LTS releases like 1.5 and 2.5), so classes / functions are changed or deprecated and later removed. New things are added and so on.

For developers is possible to maintaing a component under different versions (I am not saying it's easy), but they need to know what has changed in the API.

Also constructs like (in pseudocode)

`if (Joomla! version == 1.5) then do this else do that`.

are used to make sure some parts of the code are used only in a specific version.

To better understand what is going on have a look at:

[**Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3.0**](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1)

You you easily see:

- Renamed classes
- Removed classes
- etc.